# Transforming data for parametric testing

Tags: normal-distribution, anova, data-transformation

I am looking to compare efficacy of five different types of traps (b, s, v, w, y) for catching insects. Traps where set at four different locations (hh, mc, mf, sf), each subdivided into four separate plots (1, 2, 3, 4). Each plot was sampled with the all five traps for the same time.

I am thinking to go with parametric tests [i.e., ANOVA (catch ~ trap, catch ~ location, etc.)] for analysis but would perhaps need to transform data prior (assumptions for ANOVA not met). What would be your recommendation for transforming such data to use in a parametric test (considering the zeros are real zeros and I would like to keep them)?

Or would going with a non-parametric test (`kruskal.test`) perhaps be a better option?

Example data set:

```r
location <- c("hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "hh", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mc", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "mf", "sf", "sf", "sf", "sf", "sf", "sf", "sf", "sf", "sf", "sf", "sf", "sf", "sf", "sf", "sf",  "sf", "sf", "sf", "sf", "sf")

plot <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4) 

trap <- c("b", "s", "v", "w", "y", "b", "s", "v", "w", "y", "b", "s", "v", "w", "y", "b", "s", "v", "w", "y", "b", "s", "v", "w", "y", "b", "s", "v", "w", "y", "b", "s", "v", "w", "y", "b", "s", "v", "w", "y", "b", "s", "v", "w", "y", "b", "s", "v", "w", "y", "b", "s", "v", "w", "y", "b", "s", "v", "w", "y", "b", "s", "v", "w", "y", "b", "s", "v", "w", "y", "b", "s", "v", "w", "y", "b", "s", "v", "w", "y")

catch <- c(4, 13, 19, 1, 4, 2, 19, 20, 2, 1, 3, 13, 20, 4, 3, 2, 5, 26, 4, 1, 7, 23, 46, 3, 10, 1, 12, 11, 1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 1, 0, 5, 14, 32, 4, 9, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0, 8, 13, 1, 2, 0, 14, 12, 1, 1, 3, 7, 20, 3, 6, 1, 9, 7, 1, 6, 2, 1, 14, 5, 3, 0, 6, 15, 0, 1, 0, 0, 9, 2, 0)

df <- data.frame(location, plot, trap, catch)
df$location <- as.character(df$location)
df$trap <- as.character(df$trap)

print(df)

#fit anova
oneway_total_trap <- aov(catch ~ trap, data = df)
summary(oneway_total_trap)

#test anova residuals
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(oneway_total_trap)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Thank you for the comments. I understand that I should run the normality/homoscedasticity tests AFTER I ran the model (ANOVA in this case). Correct me if I am wrong. Looking at the plots it seems as though residuals of the ANOVA are not homoscedastic. How would I go forward now to properly test the residuals for normality (Shapiro?)? Also, does this mean that I should indeed transform my data prior to running the model? I am an absolute beginner and  I appreciate any suggestions on how to move forward from here.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Luca. Because choosing a transformation is a *quantitative* exercise and you supply only vague *qualitative* information it's impossible to answer your question without more information.  If you can supply a clearer description of your data, please do so by editing your question. However, experience shows that count data (with zeros) are often better expressed with a square root or similar transformation, which tends to make the residual distributions both less skewed and more homoscedastic.

Comment: With `shapiro.test(df$catch)` you test for the marginal normality of the outcome. That is, you ignore the fact that you observed the outcome under 5 (potentially) very different conditions. This is not useful. (And the traps do appear to result in very different catch. Try for example `stripchart(catch ~ trap, method = "stack")`.) This doesn't mean test for normality 5 times in each condition. It would be better to skip testing the Ys for normality altogether, fit the model (ANOVA?) and then check the normality of the residuals.